# How can I see what is on the Nautilus progress bar

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, nautilus

First, I *have* a Nautilus progress bar.

However, it is really frustrating because the words keep getting truncated to where I can't see what it says because the little progress bar window is too small.

Is there any way I can possibly expand this little window so that I can *actually* read what it is supposed to say?

nautilus version 1:3.20.4-0ubuntu2